# Cannot Figure out the error with my code(Qbasic 64bit)

Tags: windows, basic, qbasic, data-files, gw-basic

I am learning to program in Basic as course in my high school. I have learned some C++ before programming started in school. I was writing a `TELEPHONE DIRECTORY` program that `WRITES` to or `READS FROM` the `"Records.dat"` File.

When I run the program, and enter `"Q"` to Exit, it works fine. But if I Enter `"E"` to input new records in `APPEND MODE` or `"O"` to enter records in `OUTPUT` mode or `"V"` to view records, the program does not do anything. It creates the file and does not hang, but it shows no output.
Here is the code:

```
10 CLS
20 Name$ = "0": Number$ = "0": Adrs$ = "0": Choice$ = "0": Mode$ = "0": Records = 0: Space = 0
30 PRINT "Telephone Directory Program."; "Press 'E' to Enter new records in Existing File"; "Press 'V' to View existing records"; "Press 'Q' to Exit"; "IF THERE ARE NO RECORDS PRESS O";
40 INPUT Mode$
50 IF Mode$ = "Q" THEN
    END
ELSEIF Mode$ = "E" THEN
    CLS
    OPEN "Records.dat" FOR APPEND AS #1
    ON ERROR GOTO 30
    PRINT "Enter Records when prompted.";
    WHILE Choice$ = "Y" OR Choice$ = "y"
        INPUT "Enter Name: ", Name$
        INPUT "Enter Phone Number: ", Number$
        INPUT "Enter Address: ", Adrs$
        WRITE #1, Name$, Number$, Adrs$
        INPUT "IF you want to enter new records, enter Y or y. Otherwise, press any other letter. ", Choice$
    WEND
    CLOSE #1
    GOTO 10
ELSEIF Mode$ = "O" THEN
    CLS
    OPEN "Records.dat" FOR OUTPUT AS #2
    PRINT "Enter Records when prompted.";
    WHILE Choice$ = "Y" OR Choice$ = "y"
        INPUT "Enter Name: ", Name$
        INPUT "Enter Phone Number: ", Number$
        INPUT "Enter Address: ", Adrs$
        WRITE #1, Name$, Number$, Adrs$
        INPUT "IF you want to enter new records, enter Y or y. Otherwise, press any other letter. ", Choice$
    WEND
    CLOSE #2
    GOTO 10
ELSEIF Mode$ = "V" THEN
    CLS
    OPEN "Records.dat" FOR INPUT AS #3
    PRINT SPC(24), "Directory Listing";
    WHILE NOT EOF(3)
        Records = Records + 1
    WEND
    IF Records = 0 THEN
        PRINT "NO RECORDS FOUND. ENTER O AT THE NEXT SCREEN";
        GOTO 10
    ELSE
        PRINT "Names", SPC(5), "Phone Numbers ", SPC(6), "Addresses";
        WHILE NOT EOF(3)
            INPUT #3, Name$, Number$, Adrs$
            PRINT Name$
            Space = (10 - (LEN(Name$)))
            PRINT SPC(Space)
            PRINT Number$
            Space = (20 - (LEN(Number$)))
            PRINT SPC(Space)
            PRINT Adrs$;
        WEND
        PRINT ;
        PRINT Records, " Records found";
        CLOSE #3
        GOTO 10
    END IF
END IF
```

Comment: Please format your code next time onwards using four spaces

Comment: The Choice$ variable isn't set so the WHILE loop is not entered.

Answer (score 1):

```
WHILE Choice$ = "Y" OR Choice$ = "y"
```

You should initialize `Choice$` to `"Y"` instead of `"0"` for entering records. Otherwise, the `WHILE-WEND` is skipped because there is no place to enter a value for `Choice$` before that loop. Then the file closes, and the program restarts with `GOTO 10`.

When viewing the records, you open the file and want to count the records. However, `WHILE NOT EOF(3)` will run forever; you don't perform any input operations on the file, so it will never reach the end of the file. If there are no records, don't forget to `CLOSE #3` before `GOTO 10`.

You might also get a "File not found" error if you view (V) before the database is created. You can use a special ON ERROR handler to fix this. Something like the following should work:

```
    ON ERROR GOTO 900
    OPEN "Records.dat" FOR INPUT AS #3
    ON ERROR GOTO 0
    PRINT SPC(24), "Directory Listing";
    .
    .
    .
    END IF
END IF
END

900 PRINT "Records.dat not found; create it by entering records"
RESUME 10
```

Notice that I added an `END` after the last `END IF`. As your program is now, you don't do anything when someone types an invalid option. I'm guessing that's something you'll work on later.